# Can Always-On Display on my Galaxy A5 (2017) cause screen burn-in?

Tags: samsung, screen, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-a5

Ever since I bought my Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017), I've been using its Always-On Display feature, which displays a clock or calendar with unread notification icons, or one of four preinstalled images on the screen while it's in the "off" state (e.g. locked).

[image: Always-On Display settings]

I'm using the Image option as you can see on the screenshot above. I've heard recently that Samsung phones are notorious for being susceptible to screen burn-in because of their AMOLED displays. Is that something I should be concerned about when using the Always-On Display feature?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking around phone shops and playing with the Samsung A5 as I am wanting to get it, and every shop that I went into there the A5 had really bad screen burn. The man explained it was because they were constantly playing in demo mode and never going off, but having the time and and constantly on could cause screen burn so be careful and maybe change the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this should not happen. If you had it turned on for a a while, you will notice always on items actually move around on the screen from time to time, so there will not be any screen burn even though it's an AMOLED screen